# XMPP library for iOS (iPhone/iPad)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios

I'm making a GTalk client for iOS and would need a XMPP library to do the heavy lifting.
Anyone know of such?

Comment: use this [http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/w/list](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/w/list) this will be very help full for you
and you can checkout the code from [http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/checkout](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/source/checkout)

Comment: You can see my answer on this link :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10312847/how-do-chat-ios-applications-communicate/10312934#10312934

Comment: Please see the following links: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup/ http://strophe.im/

Answer (score 21):

There's a single Objective-C library ([xmppframework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework)) listed on the [XMPP Standards Foundation site](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/), although if this doesn't prove to be suitable you should be able to get the C/C++ libraries up and running with some wrangling.