# Messaging app - web server

Tags: android, ios, web-services, java-me, mobile-application

Am planning to develop instant messaging app which will be cross-platform (j2me, android, ios).

So i just need to find out the ways/techniques by which communication will take place among the user.
e.g - 
1) Direct instant messaging between user without web server interaction.
2) messaging between users through the server.

Second options looks good for me.

But am new to this web server era..
So need to know below things.

1) Is there any need to get new web server and code web services for communication.
2) If yes what are the available options for getting web servers.

Thanks
Vishal

Answer (score 0):

You should check for [XMPP](http://xmpp.org/).For Android check https://github.com/mar-v-in/XMPP-for-Android.
For iOS check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4734596/xmpp-library-for-ios-iphone-ipad).